# How to allow curly braces in href attributes inside content that is processed with HTML Purifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier, craftcms

I have a redactor type field in my CMS (I use Craft CMS), where the user can enter some "variables" like so:

**"Hello, {name}"**

The only problem is that, when HTML purifier is enabled, it strips all such "variables" that are in href attributes and replaces them with a code.
For example:

```
<a href="tel:{client tel}">{client tel}</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="tel:7207">{client tel}</a>
```

I can of course disable HTML purifier, but I would rather not. I'm just having difficulty in finding the correct purifier config for allowing the desired behavior. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: I cannot confirm this behaviour

Comment: I just tested this in a fresh Craft3 install with Redactor plugin. Although I do not find a Purifier on/off switch anywhere, the HTML output is as expected. And I did try with and without purify filter.
```
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>{{ entry.getLink() }} – <a href="#" title="{{ entry.test|striptags|purify }}">{{ entry.test|purify }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
``` 
Output is:
```
<a href="#" title="Hello, {name}"><p>Hello, {name}</p></a>
```
What are you trying to do here? Pre-rendering Email templates? Whats the non-Twig placeholder for?

Comment: The usual way to do this is (1) save the un-purified HTML if you need it across sessions (not sure if you do, I don't know what your use-case is, exactly), (2) purify it on output whenever you need to display it in a preview; then when you want to render it with values (3) do variable substitution *first*, (4) run HTML Purifier on the result. You'll actually want to run HTML Purifier on the result anyway, because "name" could be "`<script>alert(1);</script>`". I'm not familiar with Craft CMS and whether it lets you tweak the order, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This specific example is the result of two filters being applied in series. The first is [percent-encoding the "path" portion of the value](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/blob/master/library/HTMLPurifier/URI.php#L182) - everything after the tel scheme in the attribute value, resulting in `tel:%7Bclient%20tel%7D`. The second is a filter specific to tel: URL schemes that, according to the comments, "deletes all non-numeric characters, non-x characters from phone number, EXCEPT for a leading plus sign." - which leaves you with `tel:7207`.

From [HTMLPurifier_URIScheme_tel->doValidate](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/blob/master/library/HTMLPurifier/URIScheme/tel.php#L30)

```php
// Delete all non-numeric characters, non-x characters
// from phone number, EXCEPT for a leading plus sign.
$uri->path = preg_replace('/(?!^\+)[^\dx]/', '',
    // Normalize e(x)tension to lower-case
    str_replace('X', 'x', $uri->path));
```

So this is really two problems, the first is the URL encoding of your braces, the second is the regex in the tel: schemes.

The easy way to solve this problem is to instruct HTMLPurifier to evaluate the `href` attribute on `a` tags as text rather then a URI. The URI evaluation is very strict, as it should be. Since you need to pass invalid URIs through the filter, you can either use the default text filtering, or create your own filter specific to your needs. I'll describe the former here, the latter is a more involved exercise.

Be aware that this will cause HTMLPurifier to evaluate all a href attributes as text, you will lose the strict validation on all links - make sure you understand the potential impacts on security in your application.

```php
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'trusted');

if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition())
{
    $def->addAttribute('a', 'href', 'Text');
}

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

See the [customizing](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) docs for more details.

The main danger here is that you are removing the filtering of the javascript: scheme. The Text filter will escape script tags, but it will not filter inline commands in the scheme.

Input:

```html
<a href="<script>alert(1)</script>">Script tag in href with alert</a>
<a href="javascript:alert(1)">javascript scheme with alert</a>
```

Default escaping:

```html
<a href="">Script tag in href with alert</a>
<a>javascript scheme with alert</a>
```

Text escaping:

```html
<a href="&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;">Script tag in href with alert</a>
<a href="javascript:alert(1)">javascript scheme with alert</a>
```

When I do things like this, I use two different definitions, one called "trusted" that filters content from trusted sources like CMS admins who should know what they're doing, and one called "paranoid", that is used for content from untrusted sources.

Another strategy to mitigate the risk here would be to allow this permissive escaping when entering content into the CMS (trusted definition), then apply the more strict filtering after the content has been rendered (paranoid definition). It's a good practice to escape on output anyway, to prevent [stored xss attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/#stored-xss-attacks).

Comment: This is a great answer and I don't like knocking on it, but I do need to stress the disclaimer at the bottom more than it presently is being stressed for OP's sake. "javascript:" is a valid pseudo-schema and there are various ways of getting past it getting stripped directly documented here (amongst other XSS tricks): https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet - this isn't something where one wants to reinvent the sanitising wheel.

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer to emphasize the risk and offer mitigation strategies.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer seems worth trying, and the security implications are not of great concern since this content comes from trusted authors in the CMS. My next hurdle is "translating" the config you provided to JSON, as Craft CMS uses .json files for HTML Purifier configs. I'm a newbie in stackoverflow and I probably should transfer this question to [Craft StackExchange](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/) (doh!). Would this be considered double posting? Is there a recommened way of continuing the conversation there?

Comment: I would ask how to add an attribute to the definition. I took a quick look at the Craft CMS code (which looks really nice), and while they allow per-field purifier definitions (cool!), I don't see a way to add attributes to the definition, they are only setting top-level values. https://github.com/craftcms/redactor/blob/v2/src/Field.php#L1017  There may be a way to do it, but that's the specific question to ask. How to add an attribute to the HTML Purifier definition.

Comment: If anyone ends up here in the future and is looking for how to add specific per-element attribute allowances to their Craft CMS Redactor / HTML Purifier config, I've answered that question here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/38833/10878